# "Failed to execute 'addRange' on 'Selection': parameter 1 is not of type 'Range'

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable, textselection

I want to mirror the text selection in a contenteditable div in one browser in another browser. The simplified and relevant section of the code is:

In the source browser:

```
function someFunc() {
  if (window.getSelection().isCollapsed)
       return;
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  
  //Send range over websockets to another browser
  sendToAnotherBrowser(...) //Send range

}
```

In the remote browser, I execute the following code:

```
 var sel = window.getSelection();
 sel.addRange(range);  //Where range is the range transmitted over webSockets
```

I get the following error:

```
 "Failed to execute 'addRange' on 'Selection': parameter 1 is not of type 'Range'
```

QUESTION:
How to transmit the "Range" object over websockets? It is not a JSON object to be stringified and sent. Can I serialize it somehow, change it to base64 and then reverse the process on the receiving end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't serialize the object itself, buy you can create an object that contains the data of the [`Range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object, send it to the socket and build a new `Range` object from there.

```
const sendRange = range => {
  const {
    startContainer,
    endContainer,
    startOffset, 
    endOffset, 
    collapsed
  } = range;
  const package = JSON.stringify({
    startNodeId: startContainer.id,
    endNodeId: endContainer.id,
    startOffset, 
    endOffset
    collapsed
  });
  sendToAnotherBrowser(package);
}

const range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
sendRange(range);
```

And receive it somewhere else where you build a new object.

```
const buildRange = package => {
  const { 
    startNodeId,
    endNodeId,
    startOffset, 
    endOffset, 
    collapsed 
  } = JSON.parse(package);
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const range = document.createRange();
  const startNode = document.getElementById(startNodeId);
  const endNode = document.getElementById(endNodeId);
  range.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
  range.setEnd(endNode, endOffset);
  if (collapsed) {
    range.collapse();
  }
  selection.addRange(range);
}
```

Comment: Right track but  setStart() expects two arguments. The first is startNode. I thought I would get it from range but in the remote browser it complains: 'Failed to execute 'setStart; on 'Range': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' Any suggestions?

Comment: Also, why are only these properties and not other properties of range required in remote browser?

Comment: I overlooked that first argument. In this case I suggest that you give your selection elements `id` attributes and send the ids over to the remote browser. There do a `getElementById` query and select the same elements. As for your second question: according to example with the [`Range constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/Range) is will be sufficient to have just a beginning and and end of the range to update the selection. Although you should probably test this to make sure if it works.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as you pointed me in the right direction. Unfortunately I cannot get ids of the nodes because these are created in a contenteditable div using execCommand to change fonts, color, font-size, etc. These nodes created do not have ids.  May be you have some suggestions to get around this?

Comment: Also, range object does not have startNode and endNode properties. There is a selectedNode property.

Comment: Fixed that, that should have been `startContainer` and `endContainer`. But as for your former question; It seems that you should look into ways on how to recognize and distinguish text nodes within a different document. Or develop your own system that charts two points in your own document and translates that to a selection in the other document.

Comment: Or only send the selected text and do a regex to find the position of that text in your remote browser, something like that. I hope you can figure something out.